# Calculate $\lim\limits_{x\to 4}\frac{2x\sqrt{x}+x-8\sqrt{x}-4}{x+\sqrt{x}-6}$ by just factoring

Tags: calculus, limits, factoring, limits-without-lhopital

Calculate $$\lim_{x\to 4}\dfrac{2x\sqrt{x}+x-8\sqrt{x}-4}{x+\sqrt{x}-6}$$ by just factoring

Factoring $2x\sqrt{x}+x-8\sqrt{x}-4$ gives us $(x-4)(2\sqrt{x}+1)$

$\color{red}{2x\sqrt{x}+x-8\sqrt{x}-4=x(2\sqrt{x}+1)-4(2\sqrt{x}+1)=(x-4)(2\sqrt{x}+1)}$

Factoring $x+\sqrt{x}-6$ gives us $(\sqrt{x}+3)(\sqrt{x}-2)$

Let $y=\sqrt{x}$, then $\color{blue}{y^2+y-6=(y+3)(y-2)=(\sqrt{x}+3)(\sqrt{x}-2)}$

So our limit becomes:

$$\lim_{x\to 4}\dfrac{(x-4)(2\sqrt{x}+1)}{(\sqrt{x}+3)(\sqrt{x}-2)}$$

but still this is indeterminate form, and so how would I further factor this, if posssible?

Comment: $x-4=(\sqrt{x}-2)(\sqrt{x}+2)$, then cancel $\sqrt{x}-2$

Comment: Okay thanks :). By the way is that something you just **know**, (like a common fact) ?

Comment: What @ReinhardMeier has written is just the difference of squares: $(a^2-b^2)=(a-b)(a+b)$

Comment: $x-4 = (\sqrt{x})^2-4,$ so we are looking for the roots of $t^2-4,$ which are $-2$ and $2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x=t^2$
If
$$x=4 $$
Then
$$t=2$$

We have to find
$$\lim_{t\to 2} \frac{2t^3+t^2-8t-4}{t^2+t-6} $$

> $$\lim_{t\to 2} \frac{\color{blue}{(t-2)}(t+2)(2t+1)}{\color{blue}{(t-2)}(t+3)} $$

I think you can handle further.

$\color{red}{OR}$

In your equation factories as follows

> $$(x-4)=(\sqrt x +2)\color{blue}{(\sqrt x-2)}$$